# Using POST to insert data into a database

Tags: php, mysql, post

I need to write a code to add contacts to a database. When I run the addcontact.html form, a new line is added to my database, but the only field that has any data is the autonumber field. The rest are blank. I know there must just be an error in my code, but I cannot seem to find where it is.

Here is my insert.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mycontacts");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['address']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['state']);
$zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['zip']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone'])

$sql="INSERT INTO Contacts (contac_id, contact_name, contact_address, contact_city,          
contact_state, contact_zip_code, contact_phones, contact_website)
        VALUES ('', '$name',  '$address',  '$city',  '$state',  '$zip',     
'$phone',  '')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
header('Location:mainmenu.php');
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

And here is my code for my html form on addcontact.html:

```
<form action="insert.php" method='post'>
            <table width="250">
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            Name:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            <input type="text" class= "textbox" name="name" />
                        </td>
                    </p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            Address:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            <input type="text" class= "textbox" name="address" />
                        </td>
                    </p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            City:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            <input type="text" class= "textbox" name="city" />
                        </td>
                    </p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            State:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            <input type="text" class= "textbox" name="state" />
                        </td>
                    </p>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            Zip:
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            <input type="text" class= "textbox" name="zip" maxlength='10'/>
                        </td>
                    </p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <p>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            Phone
                        </td>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                            <input type="text" class= "textbox" name="phone" />
                        </td>
                    </p>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <center>
                        <br>
                        <input type='submit' class= "submitbutton" value="Submit"/>
```

I did echo out my $sql, and this is the error I get:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 7


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: address in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 8


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: city in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 9


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: state in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 10


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: zip in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 11


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: phone in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 12

INSERT INTO Contacts (contac_id, contact_name, contact_address, contact_city,   
contact_state, contact_zip_code, contact_phones, contact_website) VALUES ('', '', '', 
'', '', '', '', '')
```

So, I then took out the echo $sql, and made sure to remove the header code so it would not forward me, and the errors still remained. So I am getting somewhere at least.

Comment: echo out `$sql` and make sure it has the values you expect

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);die();` inside `insert.php` and see if form values are coming empty. Also I see the definition of `$phone` missing from the posted code

Comment: Make sure contact_id is autoincrement. Also var_dump $_POST and see what is missing. Check error_log.

Comment: Remember to close the form `</form>`. Also, you seem to have `contac_id` instead of `contact_id`, surely that can't be intentional.

Comment: Is 'contac_id' meant to be 'contact_id' ?

Comment: I know contac_id looks funny, I miss-typed in my database, so I have just been using contac_id for now. I did echo out $sql, and it prints this: ' INSERT INTO Contacts (contac_id, contact_name, contact_address, contact_city, contact_state, contact_zip_code, contact_phones, contact_website) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '') ' Unless I am echoing out wrong. As for the definition of $phone, I just did not copy and paste that line of code onto the above question. I will edit that now.

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined index: address in D:\wamp\www\it665\insert.php on line 8` means that you don't have a `$_POST['address']`.  You are not sending POST data that you think you are.

Do a `var_dump` on the `$_POST` array and see what's in it.

Comment: I did a 'var_dump' for each of my varaibles, and I got this:  `string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)
string '' (length=0)` I am assuming this is because my code is not reading my data that was entered on the form.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the results of `var_dump($_POST)`. Clearly your variables are not getting populated, so let's see what IS in the POST.  Also, try looking in `$_GET` in case you're doing GETs instead of POSTs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if `contac_id` is auto-increment)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Contacts (contact_name, contact_address, contact_city,          
contact_state, contact_zip_code, contact_phones, contact_website)
        VALUES ('$name',  '$address',  '$city',  '$state',  '$zip',     
'$phone',  '')";
```

Instead of

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Contacts (contac_id, contact_name, contact_address, contact_city,          
contact_state, contact_zip_code, contact_phones, contact_website)
        VALUES ('', '$name',  '$address',  '$city',  '$state',  '$zip',     
'$phone',  '')";
```

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.